# In react, when src directory symlinked from other directory within react app, throws rendor error

Tags: reactjs, jsx

When we symliked `src` directory from somewhere, within react app throws error 'jsx' isn't currently enabled.

If the directory is not sym-linked, and instead, a regular directory, -- no problems.

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (13:3):

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

#### Steps to Reproduce in `Linux OS`,

Move `src` directory somewhere, create symlink by following commands.

> `sudo ln -s 'somewhere/src' 'react-app-project-path/src'`

> `npm run start` or `yarn start`

Throws below error

[image: react-start-error]